# Are there additionnal abilities that would make you unable to get all Toads/Collectibles on the first run through an area?

Tags: paper-mario-the-origami-king

Sometimes it feels like a jump is just a little too far, or a little to high, or there's a box in the way so you miss some collectibles because you can't seem to go get them yet.

I chalked them up as 'I'm gonna get an ability later that makes it so I can jump longer/higher or break that kind of box' but after 2 out of I assume 6 main regions, I still did not get any additional abilities.

So can you get all toads/collectibles as soon as a region is clear of its streamer (some collectibles can be blocked by it) or do you get some abilities later in the game that will help to get them (or the toad/collectible is impossible to get without)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now finished the game and got all toads, I can say: there is no additionnal ability that unlocks getting some toads. BUT! Some toads and collectibles are locked by getting another toad later in the game (like one owns the mansion in Toad Town, so you cant get a collectible until you save him and he unlocks the doors to his mansion.)

So yeah, if you think you can 100% a zone before moving out, you cant.